# On degree (winding number) of a loop in $\mathbb C^*$

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $\gamma: \mathbb R/\mathbb Z \to \mathbb C^*=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ be a smooth loop. We have an associated degree $\deg(\gamma)\in\mathbb Z$ (also called winding number).

Now, suppose
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|}\right)=i \cdot \varphi(t) \cdot \frac{\gamma(t)}{|\gamma(t)|}
$$
for some real-valued function $\varphi:\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$.

**Question:** Can we compute the $\deg(\gamma)$ by using the function $\varphi(t)$?
For example, if $\varphi(t)>0$ is always positive, can we conclude that $\deg(\gamma)>0$ or $\deg(\gamma)<0$?

Comment: If $\mu=\frac{\gamma}{|\gamma|}$ then $\mu(t)=\mu(0)e^{i h(t)}$ for $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $h(0)=0,h(1)=2\pi n,$ for some integer $n.$ And $\mu’(t)=ih’(t) \mu(t).$ However, not sure how to show $h$ exists without topology, and once you’ve got it, why $h’$ exists. But $n$ is the winding number, and $h’=\varphi,$ so $$n=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^1\varphi(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: You wrote how to show that $h$ exists. It is the solution to the differential equation $\mu’(t)=ih’(t) \mu(t).$